# how to customize menu template in django-cms?

Tags: django-cms

Can anyone supply me a sample of customizing the django-cms menu template, please?

I have tried to look for the default `menu.html` in the `cms` package folder, but can't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It's in the `menus` package. See https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/menus/templates/menu/menu.html

Comment: I tried similar like this.But didn't worked perfectly.Can please look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59980497/changing-style-of-default-django-cms-menu-not-working-properly)