# django-cms: How to create custom menu like image?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

I'm new with django-cms and i want to add menu like image i post.
I have read the doc but i don't know how to create my custom menu.

I want to get something like this html code (Please add me explain):
some place in code i have .col-4, and another place i have .col-3 look image and code for more comprehension.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="toggle-menu">
    <i class="fa icon_menu"></i>
</li>
<li class="first">
    <a href="#">Accueil</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="photographie.html">Photographie</a>
    <div class="megamenu full">
         <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-4">
                       <ul class="megamenu-list">
                            <li class="title">Présentation</li>
                            <li><a href="">A propos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                       <ul class="megamenu-list">
                            <li class="title">Evènements</li>
                            <li><a href="">Mariage</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Portrait</a></li>
                        </ul>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-4">
                       <ul class="megamenu-list">
                           <li class="title">Entreprise et institutions</li>
                           <li><a href="">Portraits Corporate</a></li>
                           <li><a href="">Reportage entreprise</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="production_media.html">Production media</a>
        <div class="megamenu full">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
            <ul class="megamenu-list">
                <li class="title">Présentation</li>
                <li><a href="">A propos</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Nos offres</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="col-3">
             <ul class="megamenu-list">
                 <li class="title">Services</li>
                 <li><a href="">Montage</a></li>
                 <li><a href="">Drones</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
              <ul class="megamenu-list">
                  <li class="title">Vos évènements</li>
                  <li><a href="">Mariages</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Reportage coorporate</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="col-3">
               <ul class="megamenu-list">
                    <li class="title">Location</li>
                    <li><a href="">Cameras</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but i dont know how, please help

[image]

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: This is a CSS question, and unrelated to django-CMS.

Comment: I have put example of html code of my menu i want to get after customize menu.html

Comment: This question does not have the level of details it needs to have. The desired output can be easily achieved by copy-pasting it into a templates but this probably does not solve the actual issue. Most likely the issue is how to algorithmically produce a menu from a set of CMS pages but we're missing crucial information. What is the structure of the site? We can't just infer it from the desired output because it *could* be that one problem is how to convert the site's structure into the menu's structure. And what rule determines that some divs should get `col-3` and some `col-4`?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893772/how-to-customize-menu-template-in-django-cms